# How to clear Skype cache?

Tags: skype

My Ubuntu is 4.15.0-50-generic #54-Ubuntu x86_64 and I've updated SkypeForLinux up to `skypeforlinux_8.45.0.41_amd64.deb`

Now I have an issue that when I run the skype it tells me that "for the security reasons I was logged off" and after the selecting my old account nothing happens. I thought that it could be because of some cached settings from the previous skype.

I've deleted `/home/user/.config/skypeforlinux` and checked that there is nothing left inside my `home` folder by `find . -name "*skype*"`. Also I've cleaned `/tmp` and reinstalled Skype by running `apt remove` and `apt purge` and installed the deb package back.

I'm wondering why Skype still tells me to select my old account or create a new one. I don't understand where it takes this information from or what else could be cleaned.

Do you have any ideas for this?

Comment: Have you tried installing and running Bleachbit from the Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: For anyone else landing on this page, there is a `cache` directory at `/home/user/.config/skypeforlinux/Cache`.

Comment: @AndrewHardiman I don't have one. Ubuntu 20.04, Skype for Linux version 8.69.0.77. Need to clear cache because files I tried to send bugged out and display on top of chat messages :(

Comment: ```~/snap/skype/current/.config/skypeforlinux/Cache``` for snap